# ShopifySessionRepository.shop_storage is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I created a very basic Shopify App, and when I install it through the `https://XXX.ngrok.io/login` page I see the confirmation screen, however when clicking install, Rails throws the `ShopifySessionRepository.shop_storage is not configured` error. If I ignore the warning and navigate into the store, I see that the App was installed successfully regardless.

My controller:

```
class SpaV1Controller < ApplicationController
  include ShopifyApp::EmbeddedApp       # cookie-less architecture
  include ShopifyApp::RequireKnownShop  # cookie-less architecture

  def index
    @shop_origin = current_shopify_domain
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })
  end

end
```

I am trying to use the new cookieless App Bridge, and I suppose this can be connected?

Comment: I am also having this issue. Were you following this blog post? https://philstories.medium.com/a-shopify-app-development-setup-that-will-save-you-so-much-time-d1357a293e4

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue.

I had this in my `shopify_app.rb` initializer:

```
config.shop_session_repository = 'Shop'
```

Then I needed to run the following:

```
$ rails generate shopify_app:shop_model
$ rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```